# Compile multiple **changed** source files at once in GNU make

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, nmake

I know there have been several questions with similar titles but none seem to provide an answer to what I need (correct me if I'm wrong).

Consider this makefile:

```
SOURCES=file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=myprog

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

file1.o: file1.cpp file1.h
file2.o: file2.cpp file2.h file1.h
file3.o: file3.cpp

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

If I change file1.h, the following is run:

```
g++ -c -o file1.o file1.cpp
g++ -c -o file2.o file2.cpp
g++ -o myprog file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

What I would like to have is:

```
g++ -c file1.cpp file2.cpp
g++ -o myprog file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

(I know I can't specify object output directory with GCC, but this I can live with; it should be possible to work around with some `cd` commands.)

In nmake, this is done with a double-colon inference rule (so-called called "[batch-mode rule"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2x0zs74.aspx)). Basically, it groups the inference rules (e.g. ".obj.cpp:") for multiple targets and invokes the compiler for all dependencies instead of once per file. The `$<` variable gets the list of dependencies instead of just the first one.

Right now we're using parallel building (make -j) but it has its own issues, and VC++ compiler works much better in one-invocation mode so I'd prefer using that.

Comment: why does your `all` target depend on your `$(SOURCES)`? It's not needed as your `$(OBJECTS)` already depends on them, one by one.

Comment: It's just an example I found. In our makefiles (they're quite complex) we do depend only on final executables. Either way, it's not what the question is about.

Comment: The gcc wrapper is just going to invoke cc1, gas, etc multiple times.  The only program invocation you'll save is the gcc wrapper itself.

Comment: @Ben indeed, it seems to be the case with gcc. I had not thought of that. However, it still would be nice to speed up Windows compilation. We're trying to unify our makefiles, but maybe we should just bite the bullet and switch to CMake...

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Did you test compilation speed with and without "batch-mode"?  How much of a difference do you see?  If you haven't tested and seen a significant difference, why do you think this would help?

Comment: @Fred yes, the build with gnu make takes a lot longer (if we don't use parallel make) because of separate compilation. Before we were using Borland make which can do batch mode.

Comment: @Igor Skochinsky: On Windows it's more expensive to create a process, which is likely the reason why it's so much slower. But despite that GCC *is* often slower. But what I *really* don't get is why you would prefer the second over the first alternative, since the first one will perform better in parallel builds. And IMO it's always better to get your dependencies right and be able to do parallel builds instead of dictating the tool in which sequence it should run things. GNU make is quite good at figuring out the order as soon as you have the dependencies right.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you want this effect, but here's how to get it (in GNUMake):

```
SOURCES=file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=myprog

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(SOURCES)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $?
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)
```

**EDIT:**
I'm surprised that that solution works -- there's something wrong with my idea of what Make does -- but I don't think it'll work in your case, with header dependencies, without the following kludge. (There are one or two other approaches that might work, if this doesn't pan out.)

```
SOURCES=file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=myprog

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

file1.cpp: file1.h
file2.cpp: file2.h file1.h

$(SOURCES):
    @touch $@

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $?
    @touch $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a possibility. However, with this I would have to do both compiling and linking in the same rule. Can I somehow keep the linking and compilation separate?

Comment: One issue with this solution is that it doesn't track dependencies of individual files (which we have declared). So e.g. changing a header doesn't trigger recompilation. I found a solution which almost works [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-make/2001-03/msg00064.html) but it will need changing all our dependencies from .obj to .cpp. Hmm...

Answer (score 1):

You can make GNUmake do what you want by collecting the files to be rebuilt in the build rule and then actually building them when you link:

```
SOURCES=file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=myprog

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

.PHONY: build_list

build_list:
        -rm -f build_list

$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.cpp | build_list
        echo $< >> build_list

$(EXECUTABLE): build_list $(OBJECTS)
        if [ -r build_list ]; then $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c `cat build_list`; fi
        $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

file1.o: file1.h
file2.o: file2.h file1.h
```